# python: sandboxing user supplied code safely by not allowing "/" or "-" or "dir"

Tags: python-3.x

In one my projects i have to run some user supplied python code.

I am doing the following

```
dict_params = {
   "param1": somevalue,
   "param2": somevalue
}

exec(usercode,dict_param)
```

So from the above declaration only the params are allowed and also builtins.

I am thinking if the code contains

```
1) \ or 
2) -  or
3) dir
```

then i will reject the code

The logic behind the above lines is:

- '\' is found in bytecode

https://book.hacktricks.xyz/misc/basic-python/bypass-python-sandboxes#executing-python-code

```
#Octal
exec("\137\137\151\155\160\157\162\164\137\137\50\47\157\163\47\51\56\163\171\163\164\145\155\50\47\154\163\47\51")
#Hex
exec("\x5f\x5f\x69\x6d\xIf youca70\x6f\x72\x74\x5f\x5f\x28\x27\x6f\x73\x27\x29\x2e\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x28\x27\x6c\x73\x27\x29")
#Base64
exec('X19pbXBvcnRfXygnb3MnKS5zeXN0ZW0oJ2xzJyk='.decode("base64")) #Only python2
exec(__import__('base64').b64decode('X19pbXBvcnRfXygnb3MnKS5zeXN0ZW0oJ2xzJyk='))
```

- '_' is found in **import** of builtins

```
__builtins__.__dict__['__import__']("os").system("ls")
```

- dir used to find what have loaded

```
dir() #General dir() to find what we have loaded
```

So can this save from any kind of misuse

Comment: What type of code are you expecting the user to run? Also, eliminating code based on backslashes means that the user could not use a new line character (as an example).

Comment: that's true. I have to allow only `\n` rest others slash i have to not allow. thanks.
i am running a simply arthimetic type code. but will have variables

Comment: In that case, you should look at a whitelist, not a blacklist. A whitelist would be "only allow these character sets", a blacklist is "don't allow these characters"